# Get red green and blue channels of a defined color

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

In LaTeX one can define colors with the command:

```
\definecolor{somecolor}{RGB}{0,42,14}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to obtain the value for the red, green and blue channels for a given color, so something like:

```
\greenc{somecolor} %result is 42
```

this can then be used, for instance by PGF/Tikz to perform arithmetic on.

Comment: Something like `\extractcolorspecs` from the `xcolor` package?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps too much ado for a 'simple' question, but this extracts the floating point values of the color specification.

Improved version:

Rounding the floating point values to integer numbers -- not failsafe of course!

Basic explanation: `extractcolorspecs` yields the model and color specification in a command, the later giving a CSV list of floating point values, which has to be split. I choose to use `expl3` syntax to split this easily and to convert those values into integer numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{somecolor}{RGB}{0,42,14}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_commusoft_colorchannels_clist
\fp_new:N \l_greenchannel_fp
\fp_new:N \l_bluechannel_fp
\fp_new:N \l_redchannel_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\SplitColorChannels}{m}{%
\clist_set:Nx \l_commusoft_colorchannels_clist {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ExtractColors}{m}{%
\extractcolorspecs{#1}{\mycolormodel}{\mycolor}
\SplitColorChannels{\mycolor}
\fp_set:Nn \l_greenchannel_fp {\clist_item:Nn \l_commusoft_colorchannels_clist {2}}
\fp_set:Nn \l_redchannel_fp {\clist_item:Nn \l_commusoft_colorchannels_clist {1}}
\fp_set:Nn \l_bluechannel_fp {\clist_item:Nn \l_commusoft_colorchannels_clist {3}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ColorRedChannel}{m}{%
\ExtractColors{#1}
\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {\fp_eval:n { \l_redchannel_fp * 256}}
\fp_to_int:N \l_tmpa_fp
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ColorGreenChannel}{m}{%
\ExtractColors{#1}
\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {\fp_eval:n { \l_greenchannel_fp * 256}}
\fp_to_int:N \l_tmpa_fp
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ColorBlueChannel}{m}{%
\ExtractColors{#1}
\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {\fp_eval:n { \l_bluechannel_fp * 256}}
\fp_to_int:N \l_tmpa_fp
}


\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}


Red: \ColorRedChannel{somecolor}

Green: \ColorGreenChannel{somecolor}

Blue: \ColorBlueChannel{somecolor}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want *expandable* commands, you have to set the relevant bits at color definition time, because the extraction/conversion functions provided by `xcolor` are not expandable.

Here's a way, with two “extended” commands for color definition, namely `\Xdefinecolor` and `\Xcolorlet`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Xdefinecolor}{mmm}
 {
  \definecolor{#1}{#2}{#3}
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #2 } { RGB }
   { % no conversion necessary
    \tl_set:cx { l_commusoft_#1_red_tl }   { \clist_item:nn { #3 } { 1 } }
    \tl_set:cx { l_commusoft_#1_green_tl } { \clist_item:nn { #3 } { 2 } }
    \tl_set:cx { l_commusoft_#1_blue_tl }  { \clist_item:nn { #3 } { 3 } }
   }
   {
    \convertcolorspec { #2 } { #3 } { RGB } \l_tmpa_clist
    \tl_set:cx { l_commusoft_#1_red_tl }   { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1 } }
    \tl_set:cx { l_commusoft_#1_green_tl } { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 2 } }
    \tl_set:cx { l_commusoft_#1_blue_tl }  { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 3 } }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\Xcolorlet}{mm}
 {
  \colorlet{#1}{#2}
  \commusoft_extractcolorspec:nN {#1} \l_tmpa_tl
  \exp_last_unbraced:Nf \commusoft_convertcolorspec:nnnN \l_tmpa_tl { RGB } \l_tmpa_clist
  \tl_set:cx { l_commusoft_#1_red_tl }   { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1 } }
  \tl_set:cx { l_commusoft_#1_green_tl } { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 2 } }
  \tl_set:cx { l_commusoft_#1_blue_tl }  { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 3 } }
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getred}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { l_commusoft_#1_red_tl }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getgreen}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { l_commusoft_#1_green_tl }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getblue}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { l_commusoft_#1_blue_tl }
 }

\cs_set_eq:NN \commusoft_convertcolorspec:nnnN \convertcolorspec
\cs_set_eq:NN \commusoft_extractcolorspec:nN \extractcolorspec
\ExplSyntaxOff

\Xdefinecolor{somecolor}{RGB}{0,42,14}
\Xdefinecolor{another}{cmyk}{0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5}
\Xcolorlet{tint}{another!20!red}

\begin{document}

\getred{somecolor}, \getgreen{somecolor}, \getblue{somecolor}

\getred{another}, \getgreen{another}, \getblue{another}

\edef\temp{\getred{another}, \getgreen{another}, \getblue{another}}
\texttt{\meaning\temp}

\getred{tint}, \getgreen{tint}, \getblue{tint}

\colorbox{tint}{\qquad}
\colorbox[RGB]{\getred{tint}, \getgreen{tint}, \getblue{tint}}{\qquad}

\colorbox{somecolor}{\qquad}
\colorbox[RGB]{\getred{somecolor}, \getgreen{somecolor}, \getblue{somecolor}}{\qquad}

\end{document}
```

Notice that in the case of `tint`, the colors are not the same, due to the flaky conversion from `cmyk` to `RGB` (that has less colors available). The `\edef` shows that the commands *are* fully expandable.

[image]